# Traversing $scope defined by a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a string that in being passed in as an attribute ("Calendar.Scheduling.field.Appointment.ApptDateTime_Date") that defines the location of the variable in the $scope.  Is there a better way to get to the location of the value in the scope than to loop through the child objects.  I was hoping there would be an xpath type declaration that could be used

The $scope layout is as follows:

```js
$scope : {
     Calendar: {
      Office: {
       Name: "Dr. Suess",
       Address: "1234 Main St.",
       City: "Whoville"
      },
      Scheduling: {
       LastName: "Doe",
       FirstName: "Jane",
       Appointment: { 
        "CallDateTime_Date" : "08/05/2016",
        "CallDateTime_Time" : "10:24 AM",
        "ApptDateTime_Date" : "10/12/2016",
        "ApptDateTime_Time" : "06:00 AM"
       }
      }
     }
    };
```

Can I get to the $scope. Calendar.Scheduling.field.Appointment.ApptDateTime_Date without itearting through the child[s].

```
var dateRef = "Calendar.Scheduling.field.Appointment.ApptDateTime_Date";
tempString = tempString.replace(/\./g, '","');
var ar = JSON.parse('["' + tempString + '"]');

var currentRef = $scope;
ar.forEach(function (entry) {
    currentRef = currentRef[entry];
});

currentRef = new Date($scope.apptDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use [lodash](https://lodash.com).  Lodash is a very handy library with a bunch of useful utility functions.  Two functions it provides are [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#get) and [set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.3#set).  With those you can do this:

```
var dateRef = "Calendar.Scheduling.field.Appointment.ApptDateTime_Date";
var date = _.get($scope, dateRef);  //get value

var newDate = new Date();
_.set($scope, dateRef, newValue);  //set value
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for getting the data.  It seems to make a copy of the data in the dataRef location.  When I try to assign a result data it doesn't bind to the $scope dataRef object.

`_.at($scope,dateRef) = moment(tempDateTime).format('MM/DD/YYYY');`

Is there an object assignment that can be used with the dateRef path?

Comment: @TXN_747 I addressed your comment in the answer.  To set a value you should use `set`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of each time accessing `Appointment` object's `ApptDateTime_Date` property like this

```
var dateRef = "Calendar.Scheduling.field.Appointment.ApptDateTime_Date";
```

you can set following code at one place in your code

```
var appointment = $scope.Calendar.Scheduling.field.Appointment;
```

above code holds reference to `Appointment` object in `appointment` variable

then you can form `dataRef` each time you pass as it as parameter

```
var dateRef = \"+ appointment + ".ApptDateTime_Date" +\";
```